# Keyboard events don't work in Bing AJAX V8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Although the keyboard events are supported in V7, it seems that V8 has dropped the support.

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'keyup', function () { 

    console.log('key up')
 });
```

The above code fails when executed.

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

I digged inside the V8 API a bit and found that the internal  `u=n._getWrappedEventArgs(t,i,r)` returns a target object which doesn't have this event as a property.

Any work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps V8 does not expose key up/down events. Note that you can easily just add this directly on the map div using standard JavaScript